# Xamarin.iOS.dll & GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll to be referenced

Tags: c#, ios, dll, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am getting the following error in my Xamarin project:

> Cannot include both 'monotouch.dll' and 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' in the same
>   Xamarin.iOS project - 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' is referenced explicitly,
>   while 'monotouch.dll' is referenced by 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform'

Both Xamarin.iOS.dll & GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll to be referenced but seems like it cannot.

How would i go around this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you working on a new 64 bit iOS project? if so have you tried using 64 bit compatible MVVM Light libraries available here: http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2015/01/porting-mvvmlight-to-the-xamarin-ios-unified-api-64-bits did a quick test and everything is fine for me.